# This python code to detect ellipse detects more ellipse than the present ellipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def resize_image(img, scale_percent):
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return resized


def detect_ellipses(img, contours):
    ellipses = []
    for contour in contours:
        relevant_points = np.reshape(contour, (contour.shape[0], 2))
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(relevant_points)
        ellipses.append(ellipse)
    return ellipses


# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('canny.jpg')

if img is None:
    print("Failed to load the image")
    exit()

# Resize the image
img = resize_image(img, 15)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply morphological operation to remove small noise in the image
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Apply edge detection to the grayscale image with adjusted parameters
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

# Find the contours in the edge map
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Detect ellipses from the contours
ellipses = detect_ellipses(img, contours)

# Draw the ellipses on the original image
for ellipse in ellipses:
    cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Show the original image with the fitted ellipses
cv2.imshow('Ellipse Detection', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code to detect the ellipse present, the it is detecting more ellipse than the present ellipse
There are 6 rings present but its shows 24`your text`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBqP.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHeZL.png)

I want to detect circles/ellipse present in the given image but its count shows 24 rings

Comment: fitEllipse is not a detection but a fitting. As a simple improvement you could compare the  area of the contour to the area of the fitted ellipse and discard it if it deviates too much.

Comment: Please show us the detections.

Comment: So you first apply Canny, which detects edges, and turns the 6 ellipses into 12. Then you apply `findContours` which finds the outlines of the 12 ellipses, which have 2 outlines each (inner and outer). Try applying `findComtours` to the bilevel image directly, then filter out one of the two outlines of each ellipse.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  PLease check, i have added the output now

Comment: I don't see 24 ellipses !?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes that's the problem I am facing here. Out counts 24 ellipses don't know how

Comment: Where are they ? (I mean individually.)